# the difference between with new or without when build array

Tags: java, arrays

I know that there exist two ways to build an array：

```
int[] a = {1,2,3};
int[] b = new int[]{1,2,3};
```

and by now everything is ok.

**But** when using *for loop* to process the data of *array*. Something appear.

as for this way:

```
for(int data:a){}
```

everything is ok,
 
but about the below way, surprise arise:

```
for(int data:{1,2,3}){}
```

it cant pass compile. and the error information is:

---

Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ArrayInitializer
    - Syntax error, insert "; ; ) Statement" to complete ForStatement
    - Type mismatch: cannot convert from int[] to int
    - Syntax error on token ":", = expected

I want to figure out why, and further I want to know whether the *array* is in *stack* or *heap* memory when without *new* keyword? and I know it exist *heap memory* when with *new* keywords.

Comment: That's because the second syntax is invalid. The array literal syntax is only valid at assignment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a variable initialization, the two forms have exactly the same result.

The short form (called an *array initializer*; [JLS§10.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6)) can only be used in an initialization, though, not as a freestanding value, which is why your `for` example doesn't work.